# Mac mini mid 2010 stuck on Apple logo with full progress bar

Tags: high-sierra, startup, mac-mini

I bought a used Mac Mini mid-2010 server. When it arrived I turned it on and it booted regularly into macOS High Sierra, since this is the last version supported by this model. I verified that everything was working and then turned off the machine.

The problem is that now it won't boot. The Apple logo appears and the progress bar underneath goes all the way to the end, but it does not go beyond that point. Is is worth mentioning that the bar progresses relatively fast until it reaches the middle and then it goes really slowly until the end. I tried to boot into the Recovery partition and the same thing happens. I tried Internet Recovery, both using <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (however, this last option yields a slightly different outcome: it gets stuck in the screen with the apple logo, but instead of the full bar, I get the spinning wheel). I also tried safe boot, resetting NVRAM and PRAM, and an installation USB thumb drive. The result is the same. Just display, keyboard and mouse connected to the Mac.

Funny thing is I had an old SSD where a Windows distro was installed and if I plug it to the mac via USB adapter and select its EFI file by holding the Option key during boot, it goes right into a fully functional Windows environment, making me think that there is no hardware problem with it...

**EDIT:**
I booted using verbose mode and the boot seems to hang at this point:

```
busy timeout[0], (60s): ´IOFireWireLocalNode´
EXC_RESOURCE -> sftwareupdated[210] exceeded mem limit: ActiveSoft 500 MB (non-fatal)
hfs: mounted Recovery HD on device disk1s3
hfs: unmount initiated on Recovery HD on device disk1s3
busy timeout[1], (60s): ´IOFireWireLocalNode´
busy timeout[2], (60s): ´IOFireWireLocalNode´
busy timeout[3], (60s): ´IOFireWireLocalNode´
IOConsoleUsers: time(0) 0->0, lin 0, llk 1,
IOConsoleUsers: gIOScreenLockState 3, hs 0, bs 0, now 0, sm 0x0
```

So, by my understanding there are two main issues here, possibly. The FireWire timeout and the exceeded memory limit related to software updates. No more text appears after these lines.

If it helps, I can also successfully boot into Single User mode, where I have access to a `sh` terminal.

Comment: Please check to make sure the RAM is seated firmly in the carrier. Follow [these instructions](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205041#three) to open the bottom of the Mini. You should remove and re-seat the RAM, which should have these characteristics: PC3-10600 DDR3 204-pin SO-DIMMs.

Comment: @IconDaemon Just removed and reinserted the two sticks of RAM, even tried a third one laying around, still stuck at Apple logo. The RAM is DDR3, but the reference is different from the on you gave me (PC3-8500S). However, the Mac booted the first time with this very same RAM, so could this be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I finally found a solution. The verbose boot lead me to believe that the problem had something to do with the FireWire port/driver. Since I do not really need FireWire, I figured I could disable it. Therefore, based on a combination of other answers to similar questions, I did the following:

1. First, I must disable SIP, so I can use the Single User mode with writing privileges. Since I cannot boot into Recovery mode, I used Single User Recovery mode, by holding <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (as suggested in https://superuser.com/a/1245838). From here, I just ran `csrutil disable` command to disable the SIP. Reboot.
2. Now, I need to deny the kernel access to the `IOFireWireFamily` kext, in order to disable the FireWire support. Allegedly, this could be achieved using several methods, such as `chmod 000` the kext, moving it, unloading it or deleting it. I went with the last option. For this, I followed these steps:

   - Enter in Single User mode (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>)
   - Give writing privileges to the user by running `mount -rw /` (https://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/285013-how-to-use-single-user-mode-and-how-to-use-it-to-uninstall-kexts/)
   - Deleting the kext file using `rm -rf /System/Library/Extensions/IOFireWireFamily.kext` (https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1805732)
   - Reboot

Now, the system does not look for the faulty FireWire port/driver anymore and it boots into High Sierra without problems.

Answer (score 0):

I would certainly test booting to a working external Mac volume. It's odd that an installation thumb drive wouldn't boot at all, but Windows would.

If the Mini boots to the startup selection bit, and lets you boot to an external (Windows) drive, but won't boot to the internal one, then it seems likely that the internal drive has died. That's not unlikely for a 10-year-old server hard drive.

Your best option is buy an SSD replacement, and fit it internally. External drives might be easier, but the Mini doesn't have the connections to run them at high speeds.

Comment: The problem is that I have no way of trying an external Mac volume. Furthermore, if the problem is the disk, shouldn't Internet Recovery work?

Comment: It should. (It was a firmware update to 2010 Minis.) I would keep trying to boot to that, at least. But assuming the hard drive is dead, you'll have nothing to install onto. You can at least check the disk with Disk Utility in Recovery.

Comment: Should I keep trying? I have tried it several times without success. The disk is not a problem, just replaced the one it had with the windows SSD... The problem now is installing macOS on that disk...

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem and removed the xio2211ZAP chip on the back of the motherboard. Now my Mac mini can run macos in hhd and install the system with remove strong dmg  normally!  Thank you for your inspiration (do not delete this is a useful comment, I hope to help others)[image]

Comment: Can you explain what this chip does, why removing it solved the problem in the question, and what else might be changed/not work anymore without that chip? Without details this looks like a recommendation to destroy the motherboard...

Comment: As you said, we usually don’t need firewire. The system reads the firewire controller of xio2211 when booting, but the firewire controller did not respond to the bios during the self-check process, which caused macos to wait for a long time and remove the chip.  Make the bios default mac mini without firewire component, skip firewire during self-check initialization,then doesn't execute iowirefirefamily.kext ..I can’t explain all of this accurately, but I dared to dismantle it and installed the system successfull, It did not cause other problems